# how to insert user name from first table into second table based on userid from both tables whle inserting other values into table2

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

for example i had users table in which userid is PK
then another table is tblmood here the userid is PK and FK to users table 
and i wuill insert some checkbox values into tblmood along with that

How can i insert username to tblmood from users table based on the matching of userid
i had gone through similar questions but didn't got the proper idea.
Any help is appreciated 
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Check out triggers!

Comment: okay , thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables as follows:-

```
tbl
id   username
1    a
2    b
3    c

tblmood
id   username
1    NULL
2    NULL
3    NULL
```

If I had understood your requirement, the solution will be:-

```
update tblmood tm set tm.username = t.username
where tm.id = t.id
```

If the above solution is not as per your requirement, please elaborate your question. Thanks :)